# How can I set flags of NotificationChannel with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A is from a sample project.

1. Is Code A correct?
2. Is Code B correct?
3. Is there a better way to set flags of NotificationChannel ?

**Code A**

```
val notification = builder.build()
 notification.flags = notification.flags or NotificationCompat.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT  //I think it will be overwrite.
 notification.flags = notification.flags or NotificationCompat.FLAG_NO_CLEAR
```

**Code B**

```
val notification = builder.build()
notification.flags = notification.flags or NotificationCompat.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT or NotificationCompat.FLAG_NO_CLEAR
```

**Both**

```
val builder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                mChannelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW 
            )
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
            NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannel.id)
        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>See you again :-)</sub>

---

1. [`NotificationCompat.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification#FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT) has value `2`, [`NotificationCompat.FLAG_NO_CLEAR`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification#FLAG_NO_CLEAR) has value `32`.
2. And, by seeking around some values with name `NotificationCompat.FLAG_*` we can realize that many of them are power of 2.
3. They are called, by the sample code provided by you, with operator `or`.

Then, your question

> //I think it will be overwrite.

It won't be overwritten. They are all kept by the operator `or`.

> 1. Is Code A correct?
> 2. Is Code B correct?

If the sample code is correct, then BOTH A and B are correct.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a better way to set flags of NotificationChannel ?